# Instantiating an Object when touching a Specific Object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, touch

I'm trying to make a C# Script responsible for instantiating and shooting a ball whenever the Mini-gun (an Object shown in the Camera's FOV) is Touched from a Mobile Device.

I already set an Empty Game Object at the End of the Mini Gun so the Instantiate() Method can use its transform for the new instantiated ball.

I know the the Instantiate() Method as well as the RigidBody.Addforce() to shoot the instantiated ball. I just want the (Touch Input) Codes so when the Player touches the Mini-gun shown in the Camera FOV, the Gun shoots a Ball.

Comment: [Raycasting](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.Raycast.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is viewed upon poorly here to ask directly for code.

It is better to ask for help that points you in the right direction, as it will help you learn.

The tools in Unity that will help you achieve what you are after are:

Physics.Raycast()

Camera.ScreenPointToRay()

There is a lot of documentation for these two methods.